# How can I change the foreground color of an indeterminate progress bar in Android supporting API level 14 and above

Tags: android, android-progressbar

[image: indeterminate progress bar]

I want to change the foreground color (blue) of the Android Progress bar dynamically to COLOR_DEFINED .But keep the background color (Gray) as it is.The min API level for the system is 14.So I am unable to figure out a way to do the same.

Trying to create a ColorFilter with the same background color and COLOR_DEFINED gets overlayed on top of it.

I have tried the PorterDuff.Mode already but none of them work well for me.

Answer (score 0):

After trying for a while found a fix for it .

The horizontal progress bar indeterminateDrawable xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="2dip" />
            <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/background_grey"
                android:endColor="@color/light_grey"
                android:angle="270"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/progress"
        >
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners
                    android:radius="2dip" />
                <gradient
                    android:startColor="@color/blue"
                    android:endColor="@color/blue"
                    android:angle="270" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Code:

ProgressBar pB = (ProgressBar)                v.findViewById(R.id.activation_progressBar);

```
    if (pB != null) {

        if (pB.getIndeterminateDrawable() != null) {

            //Getting the progress element from the indeterminate progress drawable and setting it to the custom color specified.
            final LayerDrawable indeterminateDrawable = (LayerDrawable) pB.getIndeterminateDrawable();
            indeterminateDrawable.getDrawable(1).setColorFilter(CUSTOM_DEFINED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        }
    }
```